# 301 redirect without index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I saw many 301 questions but I haven't found a solution for mine so I'll just post it here.

The standard 301 looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.301redirect\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.301redirect.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Well, when I surf to my website I end up on www.domain.tld/index.php/restofquery. I want to get to www.domain.tld/ when I surf to domain.tld and I also want no index.php in any other query. So domain.tld/articlebla should be www.domain.tld/articlebla.

Any way to accomplish this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

To simply add on the `www` you would do:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^301redirect\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.301redirect.de/ [R=301,NC]
```

To also add on the other urls parts and `www`, you would do:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^301redirect\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://www.301redirect.de/$1/ [R=301,NC]
```

If you mean you **don't** want the original query string on the redirect url then this will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.301redirect\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.301redirect.de/$1/? [L,R=301]
```

Adding a `?` to the end of the `RewriteRule` means that the query string won't get added.

Comment: Hey. I meant that when surfing to the domain.tld directly the server / the htaccess should just redirect to www.domain.tld. But if surf to domain.tld/query1/query2/ etc., there should be a www. appended at the beginning but no index.php.

Currently it's like domain.tld -> www.domain.tld/index.php
and domain.tld/query1/query2/ -> www.domain.tld/index.php/query1/query2/

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) I updated my htaccess but now I get a internal server error. To be a little more exact - there should be a www. everywhere but a index.php nowhere. Sorry for torturing you :(

Comment: Still getting a internal :( I'm using the secound one :o anywhting wrong?